# How to change code so map displays data properly when hovering?

Tags: javascript

I am editing code for an interactive map as a project, I found the map already online shared as a free project to tinker with... Currently, It displays data when you hover over each country. as follows.

```
function drawRegionsMap() {

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

['Country', 'Customer Count', 'Agent Count'],

['Argentina', 999000, 100],
```

Currently when you hover over you see this ...

> **Canada**
>
> **Customer Count:** 1,110,000
>
> **Agent Count:** 590

Here is the issue I am running into. I would like to display (below) data instead. But when I input the changes it doesn't display. I'm guessing because it isn't numerical anymore. What am I doing wrong? I have about 140 countries I need to edit and change. lol

Here is what I want to display when hovering.

> **Canada**
>
> **Currency:** CAD
>
> **Payments:** Yes
>
> **Collections:** Yes
>
> **Local Capabilities**: Yes
>
> **Payment Timeframe:** Same Day*

I tried this:

Here was what I did to test it but it didn't work

```
['Country', 'Currency', 'Payments'],

['Argentina', 'CAD', 'YES'],
```

Here is the original code. I know I have to change something with how to columns display data etc, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use the HTML format, like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: drawVisualization});

function drawVisualization() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
        ['Argentina', '<div>Currency: CAD</div><div>Payments: Yes</div>'],
        ['Russia', '<div>Currency: RUB</div><div>Payments: Yes</div>'],
        ['US', '<div>Currency: USD</div><div>Payments: Yes</div>']])
    var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        }
    });
}

<script src="//www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

See in playground: http://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/opfe4dLc/5/#&togetherjs=GBjU6vwed8

Comment: Wow thank you so much Dennis!  I input those changes .. but for some reason the map now shows  ...Payments: Yes <div></div> ...when you hover..it actually shows the div.

This is the code I am using. [https://visibleranking.com/add-interactive-world-map-with-mouseover-data-to-your-site.php] I replaced starting at ... function drawVisualization() {

and I only input up to the country list ...is that why I am having an issue?

Comment: Hey Denis! I'm inside your fiddle right now - I've put in the full code of what I am working on below what you input.

http://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/opfe4dLc/5/#

Comment: Hm, I don't see your changes in playground. Do you set tooltip.isHtml to true?

Comment: Ok I got it working - but the only thing that has changed now is the color of the map is now green and my colour axis doesn't display ...

Comment: 'code' function drawRegionsMap() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Country', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
        ['Canada', '<div><b>Currency</b>: CAD</div><div><b>Payments</b>: Yes</div><div><b>Send Local</b>: Yes</div><div><b>Receive Local</b>: Yes</div>'],
]);

var options = {
colorAxis: {colors: ['#DCB13C']},
legend: 'none',
width:980,
height:700,
tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        }
};;

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('regions_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>'

Comment: Well Denis - I got it all working....but the countries are now all green. But i got everything to display properly and adjusted sizing of my map. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you don't mind --- why won't my color var options wont display properly?

var options = {
colorAxis: {colors: ['DCB13C']},

Comment: Hello. Use `defaultColor` for color to assign to regions and `datalessRegionColor` for another. Example: `datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0', defaultColor: '#f5f5f5'` https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#coloring-your-chart

Comment: I'm so far out of my skillset - but I am stuck on this so bad - i can't thank you enough for your guidance so far. It took me almost 10 hours to do the country list yesterday.

Comment: here is my fiddle - you can see what I've done so far https://jsfiddle.net/jrburmeister/x61nkyd0/13/ 
@DenisStukalov

Comment: Hi, Johnny. I made small fixed in your code, please see (i forked from your brunch). What you try do? if you have country list from another format, then maybe, I can write reducer for convert data to map format. My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/79Lwgpba/

Comment: that is the only country list format I have right now - I'm very beginner and entered in every country manually by myself